# Azure Ad machine to machine authentication using client credentials node js

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I want to make a non-browser application to authenticate a user to AzureAD without all the re-directions and get the token in the end. I can only use nodeJS. 
I found the library on github that supports this scenario [NodeJS library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/tree/master).

The system I am trying to use this sample uses azure ad which performs realm discovery and sends the user to ADFS to log in.

When the ADFS server is discovered and asked for metadata it returns the xml but the aplication reloads and the whole process starts again.

This is the last log in the console i can see:
MEX: VERBOSE: Retrieving mex at: https://adfsservername/adfs/services/trust/mex

Comment: Are you using Azure AD B2C or regular Azure AD?

Comment: Also, for service to service calls (which is what client credentials is for), you shouldn't be talking to ADFS nor its metadata. You should configure your flow with Azure AD's metadata endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/). In a federated tenant, the federation only comes into play for user flows.

Comment: I have been investigating some more and found that the reload happens when the request is sent in this function OAuth2Client.prototype.getToken in the oauth2client.js

Answer (score 1):

When using the client credentials flow to authenticate with Azure AD, there is no need to interact with ADFS. You can refer the code sample provided by the [azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/tree/master):

**Server to Server via Client Credentials:**

```
var adal = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';
var tenant = 'myTenant';
var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var clientId = 'yourClientIdHere';
var clientSecret = 'yourAADIssuedClientSecretHere'
var resource = '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000';

var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, clientId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(tokenResponse);
  }
});
```